# How does look xml file for setBackgroundResource() of dynamically created TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I create application GUI in the code (without layout xml file). The java code is:

```
TextView tv = new TextView (this);
tv.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.custom_tv);
```

I don't know how should look this custom_tv.xml file.
I tried to write it in such a way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/chat_ScrollView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

           <TextView android:id="@+id/chat_text_chat"
              android:text="center chat" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:singleLine="false" />
        </ScrollView>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

But it didn't work. So, how should look this xml file? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with background. I mean we know whats wrong, tell us further clearly what do you want to do..(i.e which type of background e.g solid color, repeated image , gradient etc..)

Comment: Hi Adil, thanks. I write calculator application and it has one line display. I want that the typed expression by the user will move dynamically to the left. I tried to use function tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) but the text still didn't move. So, I try now to do it with xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure why you are doing this using a ScrollView assuming that you add multiple textviews everytime? Wouldn't it be better to replace the scrollview with one textview and change the text if you need to?

Comment: Hi Jardi. Thanks for the answer. It's a good idea. I can type every time only X last signs, but I think that I can't know how many signs are in the row for different types of cell phones.